# Are there different versions of Blade Runner 2049?

Tags: blade-runner-2049

I am watching on HBO and I am pretty sure there is dialog I had not heard before. For example, K tells his boss about finding kid who was placed into a "service job" -- I don't recall this line before. Many other differences I think.

Answer (score 5):

## No.

From an interview with the director of the film:

> Director Denis Villeneuve says there will only be one version of Blade Runner 2049, unlike the first film, which had multiple versions. We got a chance to speak to the director of the upcoming sequel, and he told us his thoughts on multiple cuts of a single story.
>
> We asked him if he was planning on putting multiple versions of the film out there. He said, “No, no. I don’t believe in that. **When I cut something out, it’s because it’s dead after that.** It’s like a branch of a tree, cut. I never put [out] extended versions or additional footage. If it’s not in the movie, it’s because we felt it was not appropriate or good enough. I don’t do that. I hate that. Honestly… it’s never better, the extended version. There was a reason. Even Apocalypse Now. Apocalypse Now Redux is not a good idea. I don’t believe in it, apart from Touch of Evil. The rest of the time, most of the movies, the original versions, and Blade Runner… that’s the truth.”

Comment: Do you have a link to the original interview (or a reference to the newspaper / magazine issue it was printed in)?

Comment: does that mean that hbo does not cut parts and show the movie with and without certain parts?